# Use a link button command argument as a panel refernce

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, panel, linkbutton

I are trying to dynamically reference a Panel in the code behind file using a command argument from a linkbutton. The linkbutton and panel code is:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlLeaseControls" runat="server">
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLessorEmail" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" CommandArgument="pnlLessorEmail" OnCommand="displayEmailSection">Lessor</asp:LinkButton>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="btnLesseeEmail" CssClass="btn btn-default" runat="server" CommandArgument="pnlLesseeEmail" OnCommand="displayEmailSection">Lessee</asp:LinkButton>
</asp:Panel>
```

The method to reference the panel is as follows:

```
public void displayEmailSection(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
        LinkButton ButtonCommandArg = (LinkButton)sender;
        string TheCommand = ButtonCommandArg.CommandArgument.ToString();
        Panel thePanel;
        thePanel = Page.FindControl(TheCommand) as Panel;
        thePanel.Visible = true;
    }
```

When I run the code, it tells me the the panel has a null object reference.

Thanks, any help would be great.

Comment: Could you paste the full code listing for the page. The findcontrol method isn't recursive so if your panel is nested within another control page.findcontrol won't get that item

Comment: instead of using 'sender' to get to the CommandArgument, use e.CommandArgument.ToString().